# CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope on DataTable - Need Explanation

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis

I have code that creates a `DataTable` and returns it, like this:

```
public static DataTable Transpose(DataTable input)
{
    DataTable transpose = new DataTable();

    // first column name remains unchanged
    transpose.Columns.Add(input.Columns[0].ColumnName); 

    for (int i = 1; i < input.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        // all other column names become first row
        transpose.Rows.Add(new object[] { input.Columns[i].ColumnName }); 
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < input.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        // all row values in column 0 are now column names
        transpose.Columns.Add(input.Rows[j][0].ToString()); 

        for (int i = 1; i < input.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            transpose.Rows[i - 1][j + 1] = input.Rows[j][i].ToString();
        }
    }

    return transpose;
}
```

I get this warning on Code Analysis: `CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope`

Of course the warning is easily fixed by using a `using`:

```
public static DataTable Transpose(DataTable input)
{
    using(DataTable transpose = new DataTable())
    {
        // same stuff here

        return transpose;
    }
}
```

***But why?***
(a) Why's the original code throwing the warning?
(b) Is it safe to return the variable declared within `using`, from ***inside*** the `using` block?

Comment: I don't get any warning, what version of visual studio do you use?

Comment: (a) You get the warning because the code between `transpose = new() ...` and `return transpose` can throw. This will leave the local `transpose` undisposed, so you need to do that in `try-finally`. See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684206/how-to-fix-a-ca2000-idisposable-c-sharp-compiler-warning-when-using-a-global-ca). (b) [No](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822687/return-the-variable-used-for-using-inside-the-using-c-sharp). You'll get an `ObjectDisposedException` when trying to use the returned `DataTable`, or worse.

Comment: @Jakob: I'm on VS 2012 Premium.

Comment: The only real problem you have right now is using a tool that you are not ready to understand.  Undo that code change and study the subject.  Questions about it can wait until you understand it better, pretty important if you want to have a shot at understanding an answer.

Comment: CA2000 is notorious for false positives. They've tried to pack some heuristics into it to avoid those false positives and managed to get rid of some only to get others in return. Try for instance naming your method GetTranspose and CreateTranspose and see if there's a difference (don't change any other code). But yes, fix first what @CodeCaster mentions, this is a real bug.

Comment: And no, it is **not** a fix to dispose the object before returning it. By definition, after disposing the object it should no longer be used, you should **not** return it. Handle exceptions, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks all! I've undone my change (removed the `using`) and flagged off the warning as a false-positive to a senior reviewer. @HansPassant, I will take your advice and study the subject in detail.